# Magically sections and positions getting lost or deleted

Tags: joomla-3.x, cache, positions

I have an issue on multiple pages, which I cannot explain myself.
All pages have in common that they use

- gantry 5 based themes
- nearly the same plugins
- the magically disappearing section is `<section id="g-fullwidth">`
- issue only happens if caching is activated
- the section disappears after a short period of time after the cache clean operation (not immediately)

Since in the full width section I have only the revolution slider I am not sure if it is somehow connected to it. So I've created a second module as custom HTML and added it to the fullwidth section/postiion and even this part disappears.

Here only the differences of the working page html directly after the cache clean (left side of the compare) and the non working html after some hours of being online.

[image: html header and full width section compared uncached and cached]

and lower in the HTML

[image]

- Any ideas how to track this issue down (debug)?
- Even more interesting, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you edit your answer with what types of caching and GZip you have enabled on your site?  Are they enabled in Global Configuration?  Do you have any 3rd party plugins like JCH Optimize, ScriptMerge, JotCache, etc

Comment: Also, for Gantry5 related things, you might check out the Gitter room as well: https://gitter.im/gantry/gantry5

Comment: @YellowWebMonkey GZip is globally activated (global conf) on joomla. 3rd party scripts are JCH (but disabled it to check if it is the cause), the plugins JotCache and ScriptMerge are not used. But I use Anywhere Tools

Comment: Please switch site to Development mode in Gantry5 to see if any other errors appear and if the issue persists.